# AsyncTask onPreExecute not being called

Tags: android, android-asynctask

For some reason the onPreExecute isn't being called. Code:

```
protected void onPreExcecute() {
    hook.createDialog(ticker);
}
```

Entire class:

```
package com.evandarwin.finance;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

import android.content.Context;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.widget.Toast;
public class GetTicker extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String>{
    private Context ctx;
    private String ticker;
    private SimpleFinanceActivity hook;

    public GetTicker(Context ctx, String ticker, SimpleFinanceActivity hook) {
        this.ctx = ctx;
        this.ticker = ticker.toUpperCase();
        this.hook = hook;
    }

    protected void onPreExcecute() {
        hook.createDialog(ticker);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        try {
            URL url = new URL("http://finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s="+ticker+"&f=a");

            HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);

            urlConnection.connect();
            InputStream is = urlConnection.getInputStream();
            StringBuffer str = new StringBuffer();

            int bufferLength = 0; //used to store a temporary size of the buffer

            byte[] stream = new byte[1024];

            while ( (bufferLength = is.read(stream)) > 0 ) {
                str.append(stream);
            }

            return str.toString();
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        hook.destroyDialog();
        Toast.makeText(ctx, result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

This is giving me a NullPointerException, I know I've had this problem before but I don't remember what I did to fix it. Please help! :P

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: NullPointer doesn't mean your code is not executed, but some object you try to access is null, most probably, it is the `hook` in your above piece of code. Please post your whole Asynctask code to here for more info.

Comment: @xandy I know it's not executing as the breakpoint in eclipse isn't triggering, and I know exactly why the NullPointerException is happening and it is not my main problem. I've posted the entire class.

Comment: First, your onPreExecute() doesn't have @override decorated.. although it shouldn't be the problem, but please add it as well; second, try not put any real code there, replace your `hook.createD...` with, maybe `int i=0; i+=10; i++;` something like that and place break point, the onPreExecute() is something right in the API and I never have issue with it, unless you found a bug that will stop it from executing.. One more, please make sure your "ticker" in constructor is not null as well.

Comment: @xandy It is not allow me to Override... :\ I put an image on the main post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason the `@Override` is causing a problem in Eclipse (and the reason the method isn't being called) is that you have made a typing error.

You are calling it `onPreExcecute` (note the 'c' after the 'x' shouldn't be there). Correct it to be `onPreExecute` and use `@Override` for that.

Comment: lol - don't worry, I'm sure all of us have done something similar at some point when coding. I know I have. :)

Comment: @EvanDarwin easily my favorite answer that I've seen here.